# getting event information for rabbitmq from devstack

Tags: python, rabbitmq, devstack

I am trying to get information from the event in openstack using rabbitmq."sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues" from this command am not getting any info count and if i do any operation on devstack like creation instance or volume, the event information will generate and it will come to rabbitmq queues, b ut i am not geeting any thing in the queues.

Listing queues ...
`9857-790d4e30b1e0_fanout_662d9b12926e4d389890e0011a3f59c7  0`

`cert   0`

`cinder-scheduler   0`

`cinder-volume  0`

`compute    0`

`nova 0`

from the following code i am trying to get the event information from nova.
`#!/usr/bin/env python`
import pika

`connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(     host='localhost'))`

`channel = connection.channel()`

`channel.queue_declare(queue='nova')`

`print ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'`

`def callback(ch, method, properties, body):`

`print " [x] Received %r" % (body,)`

`channel.basic_consume(callback,`
`queue='nova',`
 `no_ack=True)`

`channel.start_consuming()`

`
Please help me how to get the event from devstack from rabbitmq.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the data from rabbitmqctl, I recommend getting it from the API.  See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27514729/1173800

Comment: Thanks for information, But when i have do any operation like Creation of instance or any operation. I am not getting information to queues in rabbitmq. Its showing zero only for all the queues. its should show the numbers of information with respect to particular queue."sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues"